# Changing displayed photo when shared via facebook

Tags: customization

I hope you can help.  When I am sharing our site www.rotaract.hu in facebook for example in a message, it is always showing the grey photo. Is there any possibility to change it the way it shows the logo?

Thank you. Patrik

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Yoast's SEO plugin](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/), you can set a default image for Facebook shares from the WordPress backend.

Comment: You're welcome, @Patrik - please accept my answer if it solved your problem.